# Create Multi-Parameter Pipeable Function F#

Tags: f#

I want to generalize my standard deviation function to allow for calculations of multiples of deviations, but still use it in the context of piping.  It appears that I am setting up my function incorrectly.

```
let variance (x:seq<float>) =
let mean = x |> Seq.average
x |> Seq.map(fun x -> (x - mean) ** 2.0)
  |> Seq.average

let stdDeviation (deviations:float, x:seq<float>) =
  sqrt (x |> variance) * deviations
```

Example usage would be

```
let sTester = seq{1.0 .. 20.0}
let stdDev = sTester |> stdDeviation 1.0
```

I keep getting the error: The expression was expecting to have the type: seq -> a' but here has type float

Help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

~David

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change your `stdDeviation` so that it takes two parameters, rather than a tuple then it works:

```
let stdDeviation (deviations:float) (x:seq<float>) =
  sqrt (x |> variance) * deviations 

let stdDev = sTester |> stdDeviation 1.0
```

The idea is that when you write `let stdDeviation (deviations, x:seq<float>)` then you are defining a function that takes a *single* parameter that is actually a tuple.

The way the `|>` operator works is that it supplies one parameter to the function on the right. So if you have just one parameter (which is a tuple), then the pipe isn't all that useful.

But if you say `let stdDeviation deviations (x:seq<float>)` then you are defining a function with two parameters. When you write `input |> stdDeviations 1.0` you are then providing the first parameter on the right hand side and the input (second parameter) on the left via the pipe.